# Paypal Rest SDK PHP

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to get my payment system to redirect the user back to my website if they click cancel in paypal, but it's not working.

**How it works:** It looks in the domain for the word success, and if `success` is equal to `false`, it will send them back to the homepage.

```
<?php

require '/start.php';

use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;

    if(!isset($_GET['success'], $_GET['paymentId'], $_GET['PayerID'])){
        die();
    }

    if($_GET['success'] === 'false'){

        header("Location: /home");
        die('Payment was canceled.');
    }

    $paymentID = $_GET['paymentId'];
    $payerId = $_GET['PayerID'];

    $payment = Payment::get($paymentID, $apiContext);

    $execute = new PaymentExecution();
    $execute->setPayerId($payerId);

    try{
        $result = $payment->execute($execute, $apiContext);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        header("Location: /home");
        die('The authorization code has expired.');
    }

echo 'thx.';
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "it's not working". What happens instead of the desired behaviour?

Comment: Are you passing success and failure in your return URLs when creating a payment ? PayPal does not send success flag back.